# $f,g$ are continuous on closed unit disk but analytic on open unit disk and $f(z)=g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f,g$ are continuous on closed unit disk but analytic on open unit disk and $f(z)=g(z)$ on $|z|=1$, we need to show $f\equiv g$

so $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$ has zero set $S^1$ which is analytic on open unit disk  $D$ and continous on compact unit disk so  has maximum attained at boundary which is $0$ so $\max|h(z)|=0$ so $h(z)\equiv 0\Rightarrow f(z)\equiv g(z)$ on compact unit disk. am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand how the set of zeroes is relevant to this proof. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially correct, but I don't think you should say that $h(z)$ has the zero set $S^1$, since after all, your goal is to show $f\equiv g$. Instead, you might say that $S^1$ is a subset of the zero set, then by the maximum modulus principle, the maximum is attained on the boundary, so $h\equiv0$ on the closed disk.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand how the set of zeroes is relevant to this proof. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ By compactness and uniform continuity, you can choose $r$ with $0<r<1$ and so that $|f - g| < \epsilon$ on the circle of radius $r$ centered at zero.  By the maximum modulus theorem, $|f - g| < \epsilon$ on the interior of this circle. This should close the ring for you.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you mean that $|z|<\delta$ implies $|f(z)-g(z)|<\epsilon$? I suspect I'm missing a point here.

Comment: You have $|f(z) - g(z)|< \epsilon$ on the circle $|z| = r$.